# ¿Como hacer que se reinicie un programa en C sobre recursividad?

Tags: c

Hola este es un programa sencillo con el que me explicaron la recursividad, este es el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcion1(int a)
{
     if(a>3)
     {
         printf("\nNumero %d",a);
         funcion1(a-1);
     }
}

int main(void) {
    int a=0;

    printf("Ingresa un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    funcion1(a);

    return 33;
}
```

como pueden ver la condición es a>3 y lo que quiero saber es como hacer que se reinicie si se le ingresa un valor 3 o menor, me dijeron que con do while pero no se como acomodarlos en este codigo.

Saludos :)

Comment: Mira el bucle do while; simplemente es que evalues el valor ingresado sea mayor igual a 3, en caso contrario volver a solicitarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso, mejor un `do ... while( )`. Dicha estructura **te garantiza** que entrarás en el código **al menos una vez**, cosa que puedes aprovechar para no *duplicar* código.

```
int main(void) {
  int a=0;

  printf("Ingresa un numero: ");

  do {
    scanf("%d",&a);

    if( a < 3 )
      printf( "Valor no valido. Ha de ser mayor de 3\n\n" );

  } while( a < 3 );

  funcion1(a);

  return 33;
}
```

Como ves, la comparación se realiza **después** de introducirlo; si **no se cumple la condición**, **vuelve** a empezar el bucle.

Comment: Increíble gracias, me sirvió :)